# Session showing abrupt behavior

Tags: php, session, cookies, logout

My `php` session is showing an aberrant behavior. Situation:

- User logs in `(https://example.com)` the application
- Session cookie validity set for 7 days. (Verified from browser cookie lifetime)
- User moves to another domain (without `https`)
- When user tries to come back after sometime by clicking the application link, session gets destroyed.
- The behavior is abrupt. Sometimes, it stays valid.

Here is how I start the session:

```
if(!$this->session_manager_issession_set()) {
            $this->set_ini_config();
            session_name($this->session_manager_name);
            session_set_cookie_params($this->session_cookie_life, "/"); //Required for browser cookie cleanup
}

session_start();

if(empty($_SESSION))
    {
        $output['status']   =   false;
    }
    else{
       // Fetch the variables
    }

public function session_manager_issession_set(){
        $output =   true;

        $session_status =   session_status();
        switch($session_status){
            case PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE :

            break;
            default:
                $output =   false;
        }

        return $output;
    }

private function set_ini_config(){
    $output =   true;

    ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);   //If session expires then ensure that session is flushed and cleared at all instances
    ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 100);     //If session expires then ensure that session is flushed and cleared at all instances

    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 7*24*60*60);  //MAx life of session cookie
    ini_set('session.cookie_secure', true);

    return $output;
}
```

What could be the reason for this? Have I implemented the session in an incorrect manner?

Comment: Try moving the `session_start();` to the top of your file, just after `<?php`. Besides that,maybe you should look at the [documentation](http://us3.php.net/function.session-start)

Comment: When you say "User moves to another domain", this means a different web server, right?

Comment: @EagleEye, session_name() needs to be called BEFORE session_start()

Comment: @Webomatik It is being called before session_start! Yes, it moves to a different web server

Comment: @Webomatik Also it works sometimes and sometimes, the `$_SESSION` is empty

Comment: I think the first step is to figure out if (a) the browser is killing the session cookie or (b) the server is deleting the session file.  Those are two completely different things (with different troubleshooting steps), but will both result in the behavior you see.  Let me know if you need help figuring this out.

Comment: are you sure user come back to `https` not `http`?

Answer (score 1):

First of all your function `session_manager_issession_set()` basically checks if session isn't started (`session_status() != PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE`), but then you start session ignoring the fact that the session could have been running.

If a session name is important for you, then you must enforce it:

```
if ($this->session_manager_issession_set()) {
    // session has already started, but we haven't set a name for it!
    throw new Exception("Session started prematurely");
}

// all fine, session isn't running; continue with setup
$this->set_ini_config();
session_name($this->session_manager_name);
session_set_cookie_params($this->session_cookie_life, "/");
// and finally start the session
session_start();
```

Since `session.name` sets a name for a cookie to store session ID, and you use a non-default name for it, my guess is that something starts a session before you do, therefore you can't see the data associated with the session you, by luck, started before.

Other option is to keep all the code, and remove only one line with

```
session_name($this->session_manager_name);
```

If it helps, then I must be right.

Answer (score 1):

Before checking any of your Session checked parameters, 
start with the basics, like for example start by simply

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```

This will simply output the Session variables you have in there, like this you see wether the server remembers the session and its variables,

Next, I think that some of the answers here are on to something, 
you check wether your session has been started but you want to check wether a session is still alive (not same thing)...

So if you know that a certain key in the session variable will always exist, then simply check by using:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['your_key'])) {
// Your code if session has been made already
}
```

I know this seems like it's simplistic, but hey returning to the basics in code is not necessairily a bad thing when you're trying to figure out your mistakes :)
So try this and if both of the above work for you then you are using some wrong statements that are false even though your Session variables are intact... :)

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your question and in the comments, the user is not only moving to a different domain, but to a different server altogether (hence the change from `http` to `https` makes more sense to us readers). `$_SESSION` is a superglobal that is saved **on the server**, hence changing servers is the most likely reason why your `$_SESSION` value is being destroyed.

**IN FACT**, it might still exist, but since you are trying to access it from a different server, the server can't find it and hence lead you (or the server) to believe it was destroyed (since it is living on the original server that started the session). This would explain why it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, since you could be switching between servers and sometimes you get lucky and are on the same server which created the session in the first place.

Comment: I do not try to access the session from a different server but from the same server that created it. User moves to a different server and when he comes back to the same server, the session is validated.

Comment: @Karooka Do you mean the session is not validated? Because if it were validated then it would be worring properly, which it is not, correct?

Comment: By validated I meant to say, `$_SESSION` is checked if it contains the session variables or not.

Comment: @Karooka I know the term validating :), what I'm asking is what you mean in your previous sentence. In your question you said the problem was validating, but now you are saying "User moves to a different server and when he comes back to the same server, THE SESSION IS VALIDATED". so in your question you said one thing, and now you said the opposite, so I'm asking what do you mean because the two statements contradict each other.

Answer (score 0):

Please read about `session.cookie_secure` at [php.net manual](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-secure)

This bounds your session cookie to a secured (so https) connection only. Resulting in session loss when switching from https to http

Comment: But when coming back to `https` shouldn't it restart the session?

Comment: yeap, it **should** - if it's not the case there is something else going on ontop. But first you should check the `session.cookie_secure` settings.

Comment: Not if you overwrite it with a new cookie with the same name in a non-ssl vhost *with the same domain name*

Answer (score 0):

Rafael is correct in saying that you should try to recreate and solve the problem with a simpler code base. You should also be instrumenting your code to find out what cookies *are* being returned by the browser.

> Have I implemented the session in an incorrect manner?

Yes.

The code is difficult to read, uses a switch statement innappropriately, overrides the system config for no good reason, and many other odd things. Not least is that it is a particularly unusual use case where you should require a session to be active for so long (a "remember me" capability is *very* different from a session). Once you've licked the session persistence problem you might want to read some PHP style standards and visit codereview.stackexchange.com